# How to extract text from structure elements in a tagged pdf using itext7

Tags: c#, itext7

I want to read a tagged pdf, traverse the structure tree, and extract the text for each element, the final output would be something like

```
- document
  - div
    - H1
      - "The title of the document"
    - P
      - "The contents of the paragraph"
```

I can traverse the tree using this code:

```cs
if (doc.IsTagged())
{
    var root = doc.GetStructTreeRoot();
    var stack = new Stack<iText.Kernel.Pdf.Tagging.IStructureNode>();
    var stack2 = new Stack<iText.Kernel.Pdf.Tagging.IStructureNode>();
    stack.Push(root);


    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var currentNode = stack.Pop();
        stack2.Push(currentNode);
        var kids = currentNode.GetKids();


        if (kids != null)
        {
            foreach (var kid in kids)
            {
                stack.Push(kid);
            }
        }
    }

    while (stack2.Count > 0)
    {
        var currentNode = stack2.Pop();
        var role = currentNode.GetRole()?.ToString();
        if (currentNode is iText.Kernel.Pdf.Tagging.PdfMcrDictionary mcr) {
          // this is where I want to extract the text from the structured node
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to get the actual text that that would go inside the structure node, e.g. the contents of H1, P and other tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an out of the box solution for reading the document tag structure - it's called `TaggedPdfReaderTool`. It allows you to parse the tag structure including element textual content and create an XML with that content.

Example on how to use the tool:

```
FileOutputStream xmlOut = new FileOutputStream(outXmlPath);
new TaggedPdfReaderTool(pdfDocument).setRootTag("root").convertToXml(xmlOut);
```

If the XML structure does not work well for you then you can look at the [implementation](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/kernel/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/kernel/utils/TaggedPdfReaderTool.java) for inspiration - the class is self-contained and includes the logic for extracting the text from tags.

Comment: This is certainly very helpful and gets me most of the way there. thank you.